# New phone old backup

Tags: ios

Currently have iPhone 11 Pro Max iOS version 15.6.1, have ordered the 14 Pro Max. If I use the 11’s backup on the 14, will the 14’s software revert to the 15.6.1 or remain at whatever is on the 14 and just add my stuff like apps and photos? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

iPhone backups do not contain iOS itself. They must be restored to a device with an equal or greater version of iOS already installed. Restoring the backup neither downgrades nor upgrades iOS.